# Left of '' must have class/struct/union when using SDL2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

I'm using SDL library for my homework at university, the program run smoothly at first but then I created a class using SDL as member like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>

#include <string>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
class Anh
{
public:
    SDL_Surface * SURFACE;
    SDL_Texture * TEXTURE;
    SDL_Rect RECT;
    void ganAnh(string a, SDL_Renderer *renderer);
    void setRect(int a, int b, int c, int d);
};
```

and Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"


    void Anh::ganAnh(string a, SDL_Renderer * renderer)
    {
        SURFACE = IMG_Load(a.c_str);
        TEXTURE = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, SURFACE);
    }

    void Anh::setRect(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        RECT.x = a;
        RECT.y = b;
        RECT.w = c;
        RECT.h = d;
    }
```

This is the declaration of variable in Source.cpp before main:

```
Anh Image;
Anh Bar;
```

But when I used this class members in my function

```
void LoadBar(SDL_Renderer *renderer, string a)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Image.TEXTURE, NULL, &Image.RECT);
    Bar.RECT.x = (720 - Bar.RECT.w * a.length()) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Bar.TEXTURE, NULL, &Bar.RECT);
        Bar.RECT.x += 50;
        if (i == a.length() - 1) Bar.RECT.x = (720 - Bar.RECT.w * a.length()) / 2;
    }
}
```

It reported C2228  left of '.TEXTURE' must have class/struct/union and

C2660   'SDL_RenderCopy': function does not take 2 arguments

Every time I access class member I got that error. Please help me!

Comment: Where is this `Image` defined?

Comment: And the Bar? Bar is not a class instance of Anh, that is the error.

Comment: Can u explain it? And I already declared Anh Bar;

Comment: @QuangHuy You should [edit] the question to add more information, instead of replying in comments.

Comment: Also please show a [mcve]. All necessary declarations must be included in the question, and unnecessary parts should not be included.

Comment: sorry. I added the declarations to the question

Comment: Please post a compilable example that reproduces your error.

Comment: On what line exactly the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an instantiation for Bar in your function LoadBar.
For Example:

```
Anh * Bar = new Anh();
```

Edit:
Ok, the declaration seems to be not the problem.

But, did you have looked here? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/3y365xw6.aspx

-> So, if you have not declared another Image or Bar variable the access to your member is not correct.